# Serialize null values in dictionary using Serializer.Serialize() method

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I want serialize dictionary with null values using protobuf-net 3.2.26

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string?>()
            {
                {"test", null}
            };
```

If Iserialize as it is

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.Serialize(stream, dict);
```

And deserialize - I get empty string instead null

```
stream.Position = 0;
var myClasses = Serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string?>>(stream);
// {"test", ""}
```

I know about [NullWrappedValue] attribute, but it applicable only to class members. I try to set it for type via `RuntimeTypeModel.Default`, but do not find a way how to do it.